# Find $\int _{0}^{2\pi}{1\over a\sin t+b \cos t +c}$ where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1<c$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $\int _{0}^{2\pi}{1\over a\sin t+b \cos t +c}$ where $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1<c$. I am lead to believe I should be using curves but I really don't understand what curves to choose and how to properly use them. I would appreaciate some help on the issue.

Comment: More or less the same integral appears every week on this site, so my suggestion is to look at one of those questions. (I leave it to you to practice on your searching abilities.)

Comment: Haven't yet come by one(Until today most of the question duplicated showed up as soon as I made a draft, but I will try to search if you say there are.)

Comment: $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x) = sin(x+\phi)$  with $\cos(\phi) = a$ and $\sin(\phi)=b$

Comment: @Claudeh5, thank you, that was helpful. How can I be sure $b\ne -\sin \phi$?

Comment: Because $cosx$ is even?

Comment: this is the classical formula $\sin(\alpha+\beta)= \sin\alpha \cos \beta + \sin\beta \cos \alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$a\sin(t)+b\cos(t) = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(t+\phi) = \sin(t+\phi)$$
Hence, we have
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{\sin(t+\phi)+c} = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{\sin(t)+c} = \dfrac1c \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{1+\dfrac{\sin(t)}c}\\
& = \dfrac1c \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\dfrac1c \right)^k \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{k}(t)dt = \dfrac1c \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1c\right)^{2k} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k}(t)dt\\
& = \dfrac4c \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1c\right)^{2k} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k}(t)dt
\end{align}
[From here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5de5tfewssffmgk/Integrate_power_of_sine_from_0_to_pi_over2.pdf?dl=0), we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k}(t)dt = \dfrac{\pi}{2^{2k+1}}\dbinom{2k}k$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
I & = \dfrac{2\pi}c \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1{2c}\right)^{2k} \dbinom{2k}k = \dfrac{2\pi}c \cdot \dfrac1{\sqrt{1-1/c^2}} = \dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a\sin x + b\cos x + c} \; dx$$

where $a^2+b^2 = 1 < c.$

Introduce $z=\exp(ix)$ so that $dz=iz \; dx$ to get

$$\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{a(z-1/z)/2/i + b(z+1/z)/2 + c}
\frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{az^2/2-a/2 + ibz^2/2+ib/2 + ciz}
\; dz.$$

Call this function (the integrand) $f(z).$

The two poles are at
$$\rho_{0,1} = \frac{-ci\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{a+bi}.$$

This is
$$\rho_{0,1} = \frac{-ci\pm \sqrt{1-c^2}}{a+bi}.$$

With the principal branch of the square root we thus have
(recall that $c\gt 1$)
$$|\rho_{0,1}| = |-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-1}|$$

Therefore  $\rho_1$  is definitely  not  inside  the contour  but  for
$\rho_0$ we have $c-\sqrt{c^2-1} \lt 1$ since $c-1\lt \sqrt{c^2-1}$ is
equivalent to $c^2-2c+1\lt c^2-1$ or $2\lt 2c$ and $c\gt 1.$

Next differentiate the  denominator of our function $f(z)$  to get for
the residue at $z=\rho_0$

$$\left.\frac{1}{az+ibz+ci}\right|_{z=\rho_0}
= \left.\frac{1}{(a+ib)z+ci}\right|_{z=\rho_0}
= \frac{1}{-ci+\sqrt{1-c^2}+ci}
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}.$$

With $c\gt 1$ a real number this is
$$\frac{1}{i\sqrt{c^2-1}}.$$

We thus get for the result
$$2\pi i \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z)
= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}.$$